# SaltStack: create ssh keypair and add it to authorized_keys

Tags: ssh-keys, saltstack

## Goal

For testing, we want this to work: `ssh $USER@localhost`.

1. create rsa keypair in ~/.ssh/, if not already there
2. add .ssh/id_rsa.pub to .ssh/authorized_keys, if not already in this file.

## Question

How to do this with salt-stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

State:

```
 generate_ssh_key_my_user:
  cmd.run:
    - name: ssh-keygen -q -N '' -f /home/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa
    - runas: my_user
    - unless: test -f /home/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

State for authorized_key:

```
  ssh_auth.present:
   - user: my_user
   - require:
     - user: my_user
   - names:
     - ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDGt6eIzilRygebgpzpRwVgja7NbXrGHgG7QbIxOhSUpwmuzJ7nHELrbbA9z+CyTFZwRtpr27OQDv7L8ox5Wp6iCFxyb5Y8sVC8vyYNoFPTfMz4qtgf0xXZRDAzzkeczuMqQubnJtanxhR7t9H2RBSxLvZkqD18O/GekCXBmR43yrBi03rVHcvumTW6m5Kg5qihq/adhVQDutiCp3ICq/blahbasd my_user@
```

that ssh-rsa is your generated .pub key

Comment: The first part ("generate_ssh_key_my_user:") looks good. But: In my environment, I can't add the created ssh-rsa key to a sls file. This is an automated system which creates a lot of ssh-keys (for testing). Is there a different way to solve the second part?

Comment: My question on how to do this without putting the ssh-rsa into a sls file is still open. But I give you the bounty. Thank you for answering the first part of the question.

Comment: I will look into the second part. Sorry was busy at work.